# Failed to install GRUB boot loader on HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8 Server

Tags: 12.04, grub2, bootloader

please I need your help. So I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 12.04 on this server. Everything else installs correctly, especially the software which I have selected. But when it comes to the GRUB boot loader installation, it just fails with a message "Installation Step failed" and the step is Install the GRUB boot loader on a hard disk. Can anyone please assist with this, I am a novice in Ubuntu. Has anyone else faced this type of problem, and how did you get past it? is there a way to fix this after the installation.

I have setup RAID 1+0 on the server.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Server version should correctly install to RAID, but desktop does not have RAID drivers. May also be better to use 14.04 server version.

Comment: I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit, which I got from this site http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201205-11055/

and when I tried 14.04, it would not find the drivers

Comment: Try perhaps installing without the bootloader?  unless you're dualbooting, then you should be able to get away with no bootloader

Comment: You need a boot loader. And grub2 is the standard. Have you tried reinstalling grub to root of RAID, not sda or any drive?